# Colors, color management, calibration two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, colors

First of sorry if I get wrong some technical terms.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell laptop E6420 (i5 2520m and intel hd3000) and sometimes I hookup some old Philips monitor (5:4 aspect ratio lol) just to use it for reference pictures and I came into trouble where Philips monitor was showing more vivid colors red is more red etc while on my laptop screen colors are like a bit washed out can I make both monitors to show same colors?

I know there are calibration devices but I don't have one and I don't have a place to buy one actually, so anything I can do beside calibration with device?

Also my Image viewer shows me a different colors than if I open image in GIMP or Blender I have found I way to get them to match everywhere (but on one monitor, can't get monitors to match this way) I would go to Settings>Devices>Color and disable color profile but it would all go to same after a while so I would go there again and enable and then disable again to get it to normal, is there more permanent solution for this?